# How to select repeated element with Capybara

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I know how to get the first element, but how can I get the second or third element found with that class x ?

Only way is by choosing from an Array like below? If so, starts at zero or one ?

`find(".element")[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
find(".element:nth-of-type(1)")
find(".element:nth-of-type(2)")
find(".element:nth-of-type(3)")
```

or

```
all(".element")[0]
all(".element")[1]
all(".element")[3]
```